# SQL Join correct? Pulling more than I want

Tags: sql, join

I have a system that is storing people applying for jobs. They are in the warehouse. When they apply for a job I create a record for them in the jobTracking table. That is simple. The issue is when someone applies for more then one position they get more then one record clearly in jobTracking. My issue is the ability to make a query to add people to a job internally based on a where clause. Let's say I want to add people to jobID=56 where their degree = "MD" and they haven't already applied. The list of people that appear post query will contain MDs who have already applied for 56 IF they have another record for another job. Who can I tell the query to ignore that applicantID in all records if one is a match? Tables are below. Query is also below that gives incorrect records. applicantID=10 will appear in my query below because he also has a record for job 46.

```
SELECT applicantWarehouse.first
  , applicantWarehouse.last
  , applicantWarehouse.title
  , applicantWarehouse.ID
  , jobTracking.applicantID
  , jobTracking.jobID 
FROM jobTracking INNER JOIN applicantWarehouse ON jobTracking.applicantID = applicantWarehouse.ID 
WHERE Degree="MD" 
  AND jobTracking.jobID !=56
```

**applicantWarehouse table**

```
ID | First  | Last | Degree
```

**job table**

```
jobID | jobTitle
```

**jobTracking table**

```
ID | applicantID  | jobID
1     10             56
2     10             46
```

Comment: Please detail all unique indexes

Comment: If you need to check for existence of a prior record, can you use a `not exists (select 1 ... where conditions for the prior record) `?

Comment: I am unclear on your requirement. In your example you want to pull all people who have a degree `md` AND have not yet applied to jobID of 56? That's it?

Comment: correct. I am wanting to pull people from the warehouse that meet the MD requirement that haven't already applied for that jobID. In my poor SQL applicant 10 will show up as someone who should apply even though they have. It is because their jobID=46 satisfies my !=56. If they already have a 56 then I want to just ignore them in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you want to pull all people who have a degree md AND have not yet applied to jobID of 56. If that is what you need you can do this using `not exists`.

```
SELECT applicantWarehouse.first
  , applicantWarehouse.last
  , applicantWarehouse.title
  , applicantWarehouse.ID
  , jobTracking.applicantID
  , jobTracking.jobID 
FROM jobTracking INNER JOIN applicantWarehouse ON jobTracking.applicantID = applicantWarehouse.ID 
WHERE Degree="MD" 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM jobTracking j 
        WHERE j.jobID = 56 
        AND j.applicantID = applicantWarehouse.ID )
```

Comment: Never tried the NOT EXISTS. Very nice feature in SQL.